# Why does R crash when adding DESeq2 as dependency to R package?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package using devtools and roxygen2.  Note that this is my first time making a package, so maybe I am missing something important.

I want to add a dependency, the package, DESeq2.  I have tried to do this in a number of ways, but believe the right way is to add the following to my DESCRIPTIONS file.

```
Depends:
    DESeq2
```

If I add this, when I build and reload I get a fatal error.  When running in RStudio it just gives a "Fatal Error" dialog and restarts the application. It appears to build, but when it does, `library(myPackage)`, it crashes immediately.

If I remove the Depends section from the DESCRIPTIONS file it builds and loads fine.  What's more, if I include a different package, for example, ggplot2, then it builds and loads fine as well.

What about a package would cause it to fail to load as a dependency and completely crash?  Is there another way to require it or is there any way to dig deeper into the cause?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: From the [R packages documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) - "you should almost always use Imports, not Depends." Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks!  I think I was trying to use depends because I want to make a class that contains="importedClassType" and I don't know how to do contains="class::importedClassType" correctly yet.  Thanks for the help!